# Doctrine - group by on count

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

Here is my code:

```
    $qb = $this->_em
        ->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('COUNT(food) as cnt')
        ->from(Food::class, 'food')
        ->groupBy('cnt')
        ->getQuery()->getSQL();
```

However my expectation like the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(f0_.food_id) AS sclr_0 FROM foods f0_ WHERE (f0_.deleted_at IS NULL) GROUP BY sclr_0
```

The result looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(f0_.food_id) AS sclr_0 FROM foods f0_ WHERE (f0_.deleted_at IS NULL) GROUP BY f0_.food_id
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use your query as a subquery, Id do this in raw SQL, but you can get the idea from:

```
$qb = $this->_em
    ->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('COUNT(food) as cnt')
    ->from(Food::class, 'food')
    ->groupBy('cnt')
    ->getQuery()->getSQL();


$qb2 = $this->_em
    ->createQueryBuilder();
$query2 = $qb->select('sclr_0')
    ->from('('.$query.')', 'cnt')
    ->groupBy('sclr_0 ')
    ->getQuery()->getSQL();
```